# Clean way to resign first responder of NSSearchField when done?

Tags: cocoa, first-responder, nssearchfield

In my application I have an NSSearchField that is bound to an arraycontroller which performs searches as the user types.

The problem is that the search field never resigns firstresponder-status once it receives it.

What would be the cleanest way of resigning firstresponder status when the user presses `Enter` or clicks outside of the search field? If possible I would prefer to do as much work as possible in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[searchField.window makeFirstResponder:nil]`

If you just want to get rid of the focus ring, you can disable it in the NIB.

If you want to resign first responder when the user clicks empty space in the window, you have to use a custom `NSView` as the window's content view and override `mouseDown:` to call the above method.